# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed but when popped

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've a problem with something that seems to be very simple.
My app has a view hierarchy consisting in a UITabBarController containing UINavigationControllers. When I navigate from the root to the second level
I set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed on true so that the tab bar is hidden

On my firstLevelController:

```
[secondLevelController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondLevelController animated:YES];
```

After that when I push to the third level, I bring the tab bar again by doing in the secondLevelController:

```
[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];

[thirdLevelController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdLevelController animated:YES];
```

(I know, I didn't like the `[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO]` either, but it didn´t work otherwise...)

So, here is the problem: **when I push the back button in the third level and the second view appears, I need to hide the tabbar again but I couldn´t find the way of doing this.**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't think this is a supported use case. It makes little sense to have the tab bar reappear deeper in the stack hierarchy. You may want to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what works for me.

```
[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
[thirdLevelController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdLevelController animated:YES];
[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

The thirdlevelController shows the tabbar and secondLevelController does not show the tabbar when you pop the thirdLevelController.

Comment: It is easiest to set it from the target view controller and improves compartmentalization.  viewDidLoad can often be too late, so I set it from init or by overriding hidesBottomBarWhenPushed and returning YES or NO.

Comment: Thank u so much dude!!! i wasted many an hour solving this problem...couldn't have done without it... :D :D

Answer (score 5):

On your secondViewController, do :

```
- (BOOL) hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
    return ([self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject] == self);
}
```

This way, the tabbar will always be hidden when you are on the secondViewController, and it will appear on the other view controllers

Comment: This works well when you need to have the tab bar disappear and reappear later in the navigation stack.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hold a bool value to understand if you are coming from a popViewController
and in viewDidAppear you can detect it an hide your tab bar again.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if(backFromThirdView)
     [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    else
         [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was actually on the same problem. I always tried to hide the tabbar when selecting a row and to disable hiding after returning to the list (a tableview inside a navigationcontroller) so that the user can select the menu again. I set the tabbarcontroller hidden inside the method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

but when I hided it inside this method, the Tabbar was still hided when returning to my list again. Now I hide the Tabbarcontroller inside the init method of a specific viewcontroller, maybe this works for somebody else too:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }

    [self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

    return self;
}
```

now when i select a list item and this viewcontroller will be presented the tabbar is hided, after returning to the list it appears again.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

You declare in the secondLevelController

```
static BOOL bottomBarShouldHide = YES;
```

In the viewDidLoad,

```
if (bottomBarShouldHide) {
    [secondLevelController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    bottomBarShouldHide = NO;
}
else {
     [secondLevelController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
     bottomBarShouldHide = YES;
}
```

I hope it could help you.