# Tab bar appearing after popping a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

I'm developing an iOS application, and in that app, I'm using a tab bar controller. 
And from within tab bar controller is navigating to another view controller.
Before pushing the view controller I'm setting a property of that controller

```
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

And I'm navigating to another view controller which has the tab bar at the bottom.

The problem is when I pop the view controller back to the view controller the tab bar appears in that view too. 
Is there a way to hide the tab bar when popping a view controller?

It'll be great if anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the code how did you put tabbar ?

Answer (score 3):

In that case viewWillAppear method will usefull. in your firstviewcontroller put this code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

So when secondviewcontroller poped out then it will call this method and your bottom bar will be hidden .

Comment: I tried this, but this wont work because the view controller is actually not getting pushed at this point. The scenario is when the user navigates back.

Comment: This method is called when user navigates back not at when user pushed another view so you have to declare `viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` 2 times. first in `viewDidLoad` method and second in `viewWillAppear` mthod.

Comment: I tried setting the attribute in view did load too.. but still the tabbar is there.

Comment: Ohh i have done silly mistake i have copied your tabbar hidden code but it only for when secondview pushed that's why it doesnt work. now i have edited my code. so now put `viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` in `viewDidLoad` method and `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;` in `viewWillAppear` method it will solve your problem.

Comment: nope this didnt solve the problem. Still there is an empty space at the bottom.

Comment: you want to set tabbar hiddan so using this code your tabbar will be hidden thats for sure. and for black space in bottom, you cant remove that as long as i know. bcoz its your rootviewcontroller.

Comment: The Apple Docs explicitly say not to do this:
 `You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself stored in this property. If you attempt to do so, the tab bar view throws an exception.`

Answer (score 0):

**Place this when you are clicking the back button**

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y+self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);
                 }
```

**I have an another answer...**

**Place these two methods in all the ViewController and manage the** `BOOL` **variable which is** `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` and `NO` **as per your requirement**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
}
```

Comment: i tried this too. The thing is u can hide the tab bar, it leaves an empty space at the bottom. When i tried to set the view frame to full screen, it didnt work.

Comment: As per you said, firstly firstview has bottom bar and then pushed it will hide right ? and when popped from the pushed viewController then it should hide... is this your requirement or m missing anything

Comment: firstview (has bottom bar) -> secondview (hides bottom bar) -> thirdview (has bottom bar) 

Then im popping the thirdview and navigate back to second view the bottom bar is there.. i need to get rid of it. if i do what u suggested itll leave an empty space at the bottom.

Comment: Once see my edited answer dude...Place that in the third View button back action.. Okay ? and in the second view button back action place this  self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height);

Comment: This doesnt set the frame properly. Isnt there an easier way to do this than this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your app's design, you could set a center object as navigation controller's delegate. And hide/show the tab bar. this question [hidesBottomBarWhenPushed but when popped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569961/hidesbottombarwhenpushed-but-when-popped) also provides a solution however I do not like. By the way, It's not common to show the bottom bar again when user browse to second or deeper level.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead present the second view controller on the tab bar controller. If you want the second view controller to have a navigation bar, you can put it inside a new navigation controller.

If that way doesn't solve your problem, you can build a custom tab bar controller so that it can be inside a navigation controller. You can push the second view controller to that navigation controller. To create a custom tab bar controller, you can refer to [Apple Documentation on Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). I think it works well on iOS 5 and above.